# What's the difference between two opposite modelBuilder relationship settings?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I use EF Core with code-first and I have model Company

```
public class Company
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }        
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime FoundationDate { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Logo { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}
```

and model Contact.

```
public class Contact
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }            
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Resource> Resources { get; set; }
}
```

And I try to set relationships between them via FluentAPI in OnModelCreating method through modelBuilder.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
            .HasMany<Contact>(s => s.Contacts)
            .WithOne(g => g.Company)
            .HasForeignKey(s => s.CompanyId);

modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>()
            .HasOne<Company>(s => s.Company)
            .WithMany(g => g.Contacts)
            .HasForeignKey(s => s.CompanyId);
```

Which one of them is correct and is there any difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using Entity Framework Core, and you follow Convention over Configuration correctly:

```
// ClassName + Id
public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }
public Company Company { get; set; }
```

Those ModelBuilder configurations are:

- Redundant - both calls have the same effect and you can use the one that seems most logical to you.
- Even *more* redundant - following Convention over Configuration in EF Core means you need none of them.

Thus, there's no need to configure relations via Fluent API when they can be discovered via [conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#conventions).

Comment: Wait, shouldn't the call `modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()......HasForeignKey()` fail because `Company` doesn't have property `CompanyId ` ?

Comment: @Fabjan Nope, EF is smart enough to know from where the FK comes from (take a look at the inverse HasOne/WithMany vs HasMany/WithOne)

Comment: This means that I can delete modelBuilder configuration and all relationships will continue to work correctly?

Comment: @Camilo Terevinto Hmm, Ok, thanks... I haven't been using EF for a while so I don't really know/remember some details regarding how FluentAPI works. However I remember that even in version 4.0 if you follow conventions you don't need to setup this things explicitly

Comment: @Melianessa Exactly

Comment: IMHO its not clear that you are talking about the configuration part, since you only speek of "Those" "They" "Them" but never actually name the things you are talking about

Comment: @RandRandom Thanks for that, in my mind it sounded clear :) I've tried to make it clearer